# Writing ec2 describe instance output to csv

Tags: python, boto3, export-to-csv

Hi I have a dict inside list, want to write the dict to csv.

Using boto3 ec2 client, describe_instance() function. I want to those tags to a csv.

Code I tried,

```
def write_csv(mode,field_name,value):   
    with open(report, mode, newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)

client = session.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'instance-id',
            'Values': [
                'string',
            ],
        },
    ],
)
tags=response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['Tags']

for tag in tags:
    field_names=tag['Key']
    values=tag['Value']
    write_csv('a',field_names,values)
```

Output I got:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| tag1 | value1 |
| tag2 | value2 |
| tag3 | value3 |

**Excepted output**

| tag1 | tag2 | tag3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | value3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## EDIT

I added the instanceId as requested.

---

If you are willing to import pandas, this should work:

```py
import pandas as pd

save_path = 'my_csv_name.csv'

client = session.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'instance-id',
            'Values': [
                'string',
            ],
        },
    ],
)

resp  = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]

tags.append({'Key':'InstanceId','Value':resp['InstanceId']}

df = pd.DataFrame(resp['Tags'])
df.set_index('Key').T.to_csv(save_path)
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to include instance id to csv ?